# Powershell -comobject wscript.shell New Line Syntax

Tags: powershell, variables, popup, comobject

I am writing a script that sets a few variables and pops up a window that displays those variables with a confirmation button. I am able to get to window to display text followed by one variable but cant figure out the syntax to go to the next line in the notification window.

```
`$user = Read-Host "Enter User Name"
$password = Read-Host "Enter Password"
$domain = Read-Host "Enter Domain. Local name is $env:COMPUTERNAME"
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
$a.popup("User Name:$user" & "Password:$password")`
```

I have tried different combinations of `n and am not able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried different combinations of `n and am not able to figure it out.

Have you tried just `` `n `` - and nothing else - in the middle of a double-quoted string? :-)

```
$WShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$WShell.Popup("I wonder whether this`nlinebreak thing works")
```

[image: linebreaks...]